# Uploading images and text to Iphone App

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am making an Iphone App. Using  a Tab Bar. The first view controller will be showing images in a scrollview and the second will simply show a text. Now I would like to add new images and change the text weekly. What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous ways of accomplishing that but what about...

1) Stick your text and URLs to your images in a JSON text file on your web server. Every so often your app should check the file and refresh the text snippets and images.

2) You could also rely on an RSS feed to update the contents of your app.

3) Use a WebView and simply show a webpage from your web server.